# math work out differential equation including sin(x)

Tags: math, differential-equations

I have a question

I would like to know how to work out such 2nd order differential equation, by using matlab:

```
x''(2nd order) = A + B sin(x)
x = ?
A,B are parameters like 1,2
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not about programming.  Subject-wise it might fit on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) but at the moment it doesn't show any effort and the question seems to be requesting a tutorial.

Comment: Off-topic, but if I understand your notation, try integrating indefinitely twice for a general solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine chars and variables using [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) like this:

```
x = dsolve(['D2x =' num2str(A) '+' num2str(B) ' * sin(x)'], 't')
```

Also, check out the last example in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/symbolic/dsolve.html).

Answer (score 0):

This question belongs to math part of stack exchange network.

Anyway, it is rather hard to solve this equation analytically because of its nonlinearity. You might use approximation of sin(x)≈x for small values of x to get much simpler equation, which is pretty trivial to solve.

Comment: thanks for your ans. can I ask you if this: x= dsolve('D2x = A + B*sin(x)', 't'); is the right format in matlab?

Comment: I don't know. Look it up in documentation.